# Condition for a continuous function to be linear

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

If $f: (0,+ \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) ,$$ then $f$ is linear?

I saw in somewhere that if $f$ is continuous, one can drop the condition $f(ax)= a f(x), \forall a, x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. By repeated application can get it on dyadic rationals,which are dense...

Comment: Also, if $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ and is continuous then f is $x \mapsto ax$ for some $a$. Note, however, that if if $f$ is *not* continuous but satisfies that identity, then it's still linear on $\mathbb{R}$ regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Such functions are very wild.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for positive integers $p$ and $q$ it is easy to show that
$$ f(p/q) = p/q \cdot f(1).$$
Extension by density does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=(a-1)x$ so that $f(x+y)=f(x+(a-1)x)=f(ax)=f(x)+f((a-1)x)$

Write $(a-1)x$ as $(a-2)x+x)$ so that $f((a-1)x)=f((a-2)x)+f(x)$

Repeat this $k$ times until $0\le a-k \lt 1$, and let $a_1=a-k$.

So far we have $f(ax)=kf(x)+f(a_1)$

We continue for example by considering $a_1-0.1k_1$, $a_2-0.01k_2$ and so on.

This results in $f(ax)=kf(x)+k_1f(x)+\dots = (k+k_1/10+k_2/100+\dots)f(x)=af(x)$ by continuity.